# SQlite - LİKE

Tags: sqlite3, android, sqlite

Привет.

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE client_data LIKE '%Mark%' ORDER BY `client_id` ASC
```

Мне необходимо организовать поиск клиента в SQLite по имени (которое расположено в тексте описания, не спрашивайте, пожалуйста, почему, такой мне ее дали), дело в том, что когда я использую LIKE '%Mark%', то в результате находятся и строки где встречается допустим слово markers (тут в принципе все правильно LIKE %% так и должен искать).

Вопрос в том, что можно использовать для поиска в SQLite слова (целиком) в тексте.
Желательно без использования библиотек.
Погуглил, но ничего путного не нашел. (Может плохо искал, в любом случае буду благодарен даже за линк в гугле)

Заранее спасибо!

**P.S**

Нашел как я считаю самое приемлемое решение. Оставлю здесь ответ если кому вдруг понадобиться. Для полно текстового поиска лучше всего использовать **FTS3** (Full-Text-Search). Подробнее [на английском](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html), на [русском](http://xbb.uz/db/SQLite-FTS3-i-FTS4/#section_1)

Если у кого-то есть решения получше, буду рад узнать.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Недавно сам сталкивался с такой проблемой - проблемой поиска русских фраз в sqlite андроидовском. Все дело в операторах LIKE, ORDER BY, которые используют функцию UPPER() и которая не может корректно работать с русскими символами. Досадно. Поэтому есть 3 решения, по убыванию сложности:

1. Скомпилировать sqlite с нужным расширением под Android NDK и юзать ее(см статью на Хабре)
2. Использовать расширение, которое уже есть стандартно - FTS3. Создание специальных виртуальных таблиц с поддержкой поиска и использование оператора MATCH
3. Создать в вашей таблице еще один столбец(нормализованный), который будет содержать ту же инфу по которой вам нужно провести поиск, только в верхнем(или нижнем) регистре и делать LIKE по этому столбцу, но результат возвращать по обычному столбцу.

Я использовал 3 вариант и не прогадал. Наиболее простой и рабочий:)

Comment: Спасибо, все варианты рабочие, но я решил и уже использую 2-й (как я и описал выше). По мне он самый удобный, хотя база и весит побольше. Пожалуй, я отмечу Ваш ответ как правильный, т.к тому кто ищет будет удобно увидеть разные варианты.

Comment: + и спасибо, возьму на заметку

Answer (score 4):

Собственно что мешает сделать вот так:

```
...client_data LIKE '% Mark %'
```

мм...

Comment: Спасибо Вам, но использовать сразу 2 Like в огромной базе да еще и на Андроиде, мне как-то страшно :)

Comment: О каком втором like тут шла речь? Ничего не понимаю.. Проблема этого ответа в том, что границы слова могут совпадать с границами текста и не будут найдены.