# delphi sqlite like регистронезависимый поиск

Tags: delphi, sqlite

Регистронезависимый поиск не работает с русскими словами.

```pascal
if (not ignorCase.Checked) then
// Учитывать регистр
begin
  SQLQuery.SQL.Text := 'select * from `' +DBNAME+'` WHERE name LIKE ('#39'%'+ItemName.Text+'%'#39') ORDER BY grp DESC, GID DESC';
end else
// Не учитывать регистр
begin
  SQLQuery.SQL.Text := 'select * from `' +DBNAME+'` WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER('#39'%'+ItemName.Text+'%'#39') ORDER BY grp DESC, GID DESC';
end;
```

Есть ли для делфи готовое адекватное решение, которое лучше велосипеда со вторым столбцом? :(

Comment: Собственно, к Delphi ваш вопрос не имеет отношения, поскольку проблема на стороне SQLite. Решение вот тут: [SQLite - LIKE](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/159468/sqlite-l%C4%B0ke)

Comment: Тем не менее, через делфи можно повесить сплайс на функцию и создать свой оригинальный костыль :)

Comment: Да, можно. Лично я использовал такой вариант: завёл таблицу `FTS3` и вставлял туда строки в нижнем регистре и, соответственно, весь поиск шёл через `MATCH` по этой таблице. А вот на хабре пишут, что самый трушный вариант - использовать `ICU`: [SQLite и полноценный UNICODE](http://habrahabr.ru/post/57915/)

Comment: Ссылка на ещё один топик по теме: [Sqlite игнорировать регистр в условии WHERE](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/402748/sqlite-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80-%D0%B2-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B8-where)

Answer (score 2):

1. Создайте дополнительное поле в SQLite - `nameUpper`
2. При сохранении из Delphi сохраните `Upper()` значение в поле `nameUpper`
3. При поиске ищите их поле `nameUpper` но показывайте значения из поле `name`

Answer (score 1):

Иной раз "лучше поздно, чем никогда".
Тоже недавно столкнулся с этой проблемой (некорректная работа UPPER в SQLite).
При поиске наткнулся на эту статью:  https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/98493/
Автор, к сожалению, неизвестен.
Но на ее основе удалось сформировать несколько функций в среде Delphi.
Если кому-то поможет - буду рад.
См. здесь:
https://roamer55.ru/main_programming/delphi/delphi_10_2_vcl/d10_funcs_db/d10_funcs_db_sqlite/d10_funcs_db_sqlite_upper/

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/786663)